# macOS Sierra install PyQt5 for python2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal, pyqt5

I'm trying desperately to install PyQt5 for python2.7 on my Mac running macOS Sierra. I've tried running:

```
brew install pyqt5
```

As well as downloading the source code and compiling myself. Can anybody provide me with some quick commands that I can copy/paste into terminal to install PyQt5 for python2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good rundown of the problem, and a solution:

https://plashless.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/building-pyqt5-for-python2-7-on-a-clean-ubuntu-13-10-build-machine/

I suppose you don't see using python3 as an option. Even within a virtualenv? Developing new software using python2 may become increasingly frustrating (more and more problems like the one you're encountering).

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
brew install python3
virtualenv -p python3 venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install pyqt5
# PROFIT
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution and it worked perfectly. I'm new to python and unix, so I was completely unaware you could even create virtual environments for package installations. Thanks a lot, going to read up a bit on venv now! :)

Comment: Glad it worked! Yah, good. 

virtualenv installs an entire new copy of python and all associated stuff in a directory of your choosing. Then when you say "activate", it messes with your PATH, which is the list of directories that get searched when you say "python" or run any other command that doesn't have a / in it (and isn't a shell function or built-in).

If you open a new shell and want to use the new python, you'll want to say `. venv/bin/activate` again to get your path changed again. 

virtualenv is necessary if you want to use python without making a mess!

Comment: Versionitis, that works only on macos 10.11 Sierra or later. 10.10 Yosemite: "Symbol not found: __os_log_default ... /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (which was built for Mac OS X 10.11)"